How do I relocate an existing jar file using gradle?
I'm working on a project that uses java, among other things, and bazel. I'm running into a mess of dependency conflicts and want to shade a jar. Bazel does not have a way to do this so I am using Gradle which I have never used before. Working with chatGPT this is the script I currently have:

    plugins {
        id("java")
        id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    }
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact")
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.18.0'
    }
    
    tasks.named('shadowJar', com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar) {
        relocate 'com.fasterxml.jackson', 'shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson'
    }

Gradle is version 8.10.2. The error I'm getting is this:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)

Between Googling and ChatGPT I've tried quite a few things, but nothing has quite worked and ChatGPT is starting to spit out the same recommendations already tried.
Edit: For additional clarification about the solution, I switched to openjdk 21 and then switched the plugin to com.gradleup.shadow which seems to be the successor to the dead repo I had been using.

General
It seems your gradle version uses a Java compiler which cannot handle Java 21 byte code - maybe compiled by Bazel.
Check Java version used by gradle
If you use a gradle wrapper (which is the recommended way - see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)
you can check this by
./gradlew --version

from command line.
If you use a system installed gradle version the command will be:
gradle --version

In both situations you will get an output like:
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-11-29 14:08:57 UTC
Revision:     28aca86a7180baa17117e0e5ba01d8ea9feca598

Kotlin:       1.9.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.12 (Eclipse Adoptium 17.0.12+7)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-122-generic amd64

In the example above, you see that gradle uses Java 17.
Change Java JDK version in gradle
To change this, you can either setup this inside build.gradle - see
How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?
Or you install on your OS a JDK >= Java 21 (this must be the OS default afterwards).
Then check used Java version again by ./gradlew --version.
When the output shows the Java 21 version your build should work now.

The error is not Gradle specific. The compiled code has been compiled with Java 21, but the code that's attempting to use/run that compiled is using an earlier version of Java. Hence the unsupported class file major version error.
You can see a list of Java versions and their class file version here: https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/
You need to ensure your Gradle build and Bazel build are using the same version of Java when compiling/running the code. For Gradle, this can be accomplished using Toolchains for JVM projects.
